# Android 10 - I want to get all audio-files on external-storage

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore, android-external-storage

I've already read some articles about Android 10 and MediaStore, but the concept is not quite clear to me yet:
I want to read the AudioFiles of a directory on an Android 10 system (the user can choose the directory).

- So as a first step I set the 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permissions on the selected directory
- Then I create a treeUri and query a `contentResolver`. (Which kind of `Uri` should I pass)?
- When does the `mediaStore` come into it, which is passed to the `contentResolver` 
  as `Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` older operating systems.

thanks for your support. Maybe someone has a piece of java code that will help me understand the whole thing a little better

I used the example from this side: [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)

Torres

Comment: The user cannot choose a directory besides Music Documents and Download.

Comment: You cannot set permissions on a directory and you need none.

Comment: You can query MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and will get all audio files.

Comment: The user should choose direcory with subdirectories and audiofiles and - You are right - "permissions" are set on files...what are the steps do get all audiofiles in choosen directory?

Comment: "query MediaStore" I did so - following the example behind above mentioned link . but gotn't any result...the curser = 0

Comment: Show your code.